# Regex - Positive Lookbehind

Tags: regex, notepad++, lookbehind

I a few files with a couple of millions lines with the something like the following:

```
9/9/2015 2:50:39 PM: Export for https://portal.gaf.com/sites/RCNHistory/Lists/RCNs/Attachments/148/Ruberoid HW Plus SV.xls Complete.
9/9/2015 2:50:39 PM: Export for https://portal.gaf.com/sites/RCNHistory/Lists/RCNs/Attachments/148/Ruberoid Mop Granule SV.xls Complete.
9/9/2015 2:50:40 PM: Export for https://portal.gaf.com/sites/RCNHistory/Lists/RCNs/Attachments/148/Ruberoid Mop Smooth 1.5 SV.xls Complete.
```

I was hoping to capture the file name on each line with a lookbehind  with the following:

`$(?<=\/)`  Of course i will have to delete the "Complete." but i figure i start slowly

but i have not mastered the art of regex. can any one let me know what i am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: What language or tool do you use?

Answer (score 1):

This could work - you would retrieve the filename from the capture group:

```
\/([^\/]*) Complete.$
```

Here's an example on regexr: http://www.regexr.com/3bp2l

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to complicate things with a lookbehind if the lines are all in this format.
You can just use greedy matching to get what you want.

```
.*\/(.*) Complete.
```

Which is essentially:

Match everything (including /'s) up to a / followed by some text (in this case your filename) followed by a literal " Complete."

The matching group contains the filename.

So, for a Regex Find and Replace in N++ you should use:

Find

```
.*\/(.*) Complete.
```

Replace

```
$1
```

This will leave you with just a filename on each line.

Answer (score 0):

Lookbehind is a zero-width assertion at a position. It's not a way to tell the regex where to start -- it must always start at the beginning. You could probably use a regex like `.*/(.*) Complete` to capture that.

If you are working with the shell, the `cut` tool is great for this too.

```
# get everything after the last slash and before the last space (` Complete`)
rev $INPUT_FILE | cut -d'/' -f 1 | cut -d' ' -f2- | rev
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex with lookbehind:

```
/(?<=\/)[^\/]+$/
```

Make sure to use `MULTILINE` mode.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cQ1vZ5/1)